# Tailwind not loaded with nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm tring to crete an app using tailwindcss and next.js

I sterted creating the nextjs app, then I runned these commands:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

npx tailwindcss init -p
```

After that I updated the tailwind.config.js like:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And, then I created and populated the ./syles/globals.css with:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

all this step by step is on the website:https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs
but still any attempt at customization doesn't work, is there any way to know if tailwind has been loaded? Was there something missing to be done?

[image]

Comment: Did you import `globals.css` file in `pages/_app.js`?

Comment: that was it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly import globals.css into _app.js

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
```

Also instead of @tailwind do below to add tailwind into globals.css

```
/* @tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities; */

@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```